# How should I represent validity of a population prediction?

Tags: time-series, correlation

I am looking to report on the validity of a predictive non-linear population model for which I only have the output prediction `p(t)` and the time for which the prediction applies `t`

Now, over the time period `t` predicted by the model, I have the actual measurement `m(t)`

With the series `p1, p2, p3, ... pN` how should I appropriately represent correlation to the measurement `m1, m1, m3, ... mN`?

My initial approach was to obtain the percent difference between the estimate and the observation (`(pN - mN)/mN` and then obtain the average variation of this set. This seemed naive to me. I don't know if there's a more "generally accepted" method for population estimates.

The model predicts what the value will be over time. During that same time we make actual measurements of the values so that, after the period, we can compare the prediction to the measurement. I'm looking for how I should represent the "quality" of the predictive model.

[image: Charted Prediction vs Observation]

Comment: @JoelW. I added detail on what I tried. FWIW this is *not* homework. I'm interested in what a generally accepted approach would be for this.

Answer (score 1):

If the relationship is expected to be linear (and, if so, does the scatter plot look generally linear?) then you might calculate a correlation and a standard error of estimate (see, for example: http://onlinestatbook.com/2/regression/accuracy.html).

Comment: The population is non-linear, and is not described any any underlying equation. I have edited in a crude graph. What I'd like to do is describe the "quality" of the prediction over the time period. Standard Error could work, I just use `Y'` from the measurement.

Comment: @Matthew Do you have repeated measures over time or are each of the data points independent of the other data points?

Comment: At time t, I have exactly one measurement and exactly one prediction. Our model predicted population would be p(t), it was actually measured at m(t). Does that make sense?

Comment: Are the observations at time t1, t2, etc. independent?  If so, a simple correlation should work.  If not, the analysis may get more complex.

Comment: it's a dependent sample on the same population over time.

Comment: It's also worth noting that we should treat is as non-Markov.

Comment: Someone with more statistical sophistication than I should chime in on this.